# Let $F$ a distribution function, $F(x)=a+b\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Find $a,b$ and the density function.

Tags: probability

The distribution function of random variable $X$ is:

$F(x)=a+b\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$ 
Find $a,b$ and the density function.

**My work:**

Note $F$ is a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$ then $X$ is a continuous random variable.

This implies, $F'(x)=f(x)$ where $f$ is density function.

Then, $f(x)=\frac{b}{2(1+(\frac{x}{2})^2)}=\frac{2b}{4+x^2}$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is the density function

This implies $1=\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} \! f(x)  \,dx = btan^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})|^{\infty}_{-\infty}=b\pi\implies b=\frac{1}{\pi}$

Is good this result? Is good the reasoning?

I'm stuck with the value of $a$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Note that distribution’s limit as x goes to infinity is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that
$$
1=\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=a+b\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
and
$$
0=\lim_{x\to -\infty}F(x)=a-b\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: Thankssss!!!!! :D